# Можно ли в этих предложениях вместо тире поставить запятую или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, бсп, тире-или-двоеточие

Солнце дымное встает - будет день хороший. 
Работы много - отдыха не жди.

Answer (score 1):

1) Александр Твардовский. Страна Муравия (поэма и стихотворения).  **Солнце дЫмное встает, Будет день горЯчий.** Дед Данила свой обход По усадьбе начал.

В тексте стоит запятая, это БСП с неоднородными предложениями,  текст стихотворный, **логические акценты определены**. Второе предложение распространяет первое, что (при отсутствии паузы) соответствует именно запятой.

А как же причинно-следственные отношения? Они здесь просто не обозначены, для этого нужна **другая структура**.

Солнце  с утра  дЫмное ― день будет горЯчий. Разделительное тире, восходяще-нисходящая интонация, прямые отношения: факт ― вывод, причина ― следствие.

Горячий будет день: солнце с утра дымное. Двоеточие, нисходяще-нисходящая интонация, обратные отношение: вывод ― факт,  следствие ― причина.

**2) Работы много ―  отдыха не жди** (причина ― следствие). **Работы много, отдыха не жди** (причинно-следственные отношения не обозначены). **Отдыха не жди: работы много** (следствие ― причина).

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Но ухудшится восприятие. В этих фразах вторая часть является следствием первой, логическим выводом, именно в таких ситуациях в бессоюзном сложном используется тире.

Запятая не передаёт эту семантическую особенность. В некоторых случаях это может привести к неправильному пониманию. В вашем первом примере как раз так. Это народная примета, а обычная запятая оставляет открытым вопрос, почему (по мнению говорящего) будет хороший день.